# Evaluate complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not able to get the correct result here:
$ \int_C \frac{dz}{z-a} = 2 \pi i$

Let C be the curve $C : R e^{i \theta}$, $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$ with $ R > |a|$.

Let $u = Re^{i \theta} - a$, then
$du = i Re^{i \theta} d \theta$

Integrating by parts,

\begin{align}
\int_C \frac{dz}{z-a} &= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac {i Re^{i \theta}} {Re^{i \theta} - a} d \theta \\
&= \int_{R-a}^{R-a} \frac{du}{u} \\
&= ln|u| \vert_{R-a}^{R-a} \\
&= 0
\end{align}

At least the limits of integration are wrong, but it looks like my choice of $u$ may also be wrong.

Comment: Even though you avoid the residue at |a| with R > |a|, you still have a branch cut with the natural log across the real number line. Hopefully that is enough of a hint for you to figure out the next step.

Comment: @Mark: can you point to any error I made in my calculation? I'm at Chapter 5 of the Bak text, and we haven't dealt with logs of complex numbers. We just learned the closed curve and integral theorems, for example.

Comment: I only took a cursory look at the text, and not completely sure of what you have seen in class but if you want a very quick and dirty (read unjustified and non-rigorous) jump from where you are to final answer, change your limits from R-a to a lower limit of (R-a)*e^i*0 and an upper limit of (R-a)*e^i * 2* pi. It looks like later chapters deal with singularities and the residue theorem so hopefully you will see a better justification later on. But to highlight quickly, the motivation of the above limits are to draw attention to the value of a being approached from above or below the x axis.